# There are inbuilt tables created by spring batch job in H2 like job_instance etc. How can we add prefix to those tables using properties file?

Tags: java, spring, spring-batch

I have a spring batch job up and running and tables are created in H2.Few tables are auto generated tables in spring batch like job_instance etc. How can i add a prefix to these auto generated tables using properties file in java code?

nwg.nca.sar.batch.appTablePrefix=SOCA_

Tried using this

and

spring.batch.table-prefix=SOCA_

None of them worked.

Any help appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you using Spring Boot? Then it's

```
spring.batch.jdbc.table-prefix
```

It used to be `spring.batch.table-prefix` up until Spring Boot 2.4.

You can find more information on all the properties in the reference documentation: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.6.4/reference/html/application-properties.html#application-properties.integration.spring.batch.jdbc.table-prefix

Comment: Yes I am using boot. Thanks for your comment